# Setting a parameter within a GoogleDoc programatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have individual user folders in Google Drive where students work on and complete their GoogleDocs.  When complete, there is GAS workflow to allow them to select a menu item within the GoogleDoc to email the Instructor that the GoogleDoc is complete.

I am looking for a way that the GAS menu item could set a "Completed" flag somewhere, hopefully as a value in the document?  Maybe by Naming the Version as "Completed".  So that I can programatically find all completed gDocs in a given folder.

Does anyone know a way that we could set a flag or parameter thru GAS that would be associated with the gDoc that could also be retrieved programatically?

Thanks

Comment: Use Classroom and have them hand in the doc there? Apart from that, you could have the menu button set "_completed" to the end of the file name, transfer ownership of the doc to you (if you aren't the owner already) and then set the students permission to view/ comment?

Comment: It's a matter of design rather than programming which makes this question to be primarily-opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting a custom property associated with the file.

files = Drive.Files.list({"q":"properties has { key='status' and value='completed' and 
visibility='PUBLIC' }"});